# I need to get from the user input random

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;

public class hh {

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the size of the array:  ");
    int numbers = input.nextInt();

    // Declare an array called numbers with a size of 10
    int[] numbers1 = new int[numbers];

    insertRandomNumbers(numbers1);

    // Print size of numbers
    System.out.println("Initial Array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers1.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(numbers1[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");


    //Print First and Last Elements
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("First and Last Elements");

    int [] lastStep = lastStep(numbers1);
    for (int i = 0; i < lastStep.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(lastStep[i] + ", ");
    }




} // end main

public static int[] lastStep(int[] numbers1) {

    //to get first
    int [] firstElement= numbers1.get(0);

    //last number
    int [] lastElement= numbers1.get(numbers1.size()-1);

}
return lastStep;









public static void insertRandomNumbers(int[] x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i] = random();
        // System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
    }
    // System.out.println();
}

public static int random() {

    int r = 0 + (int) (Math.random() * (101 - 0)) + 0;
    return r;

}
```

My program ask the user to enter a number, then if 10 is entered 10 random numbers are created. With those 10 numbers I need to get the first and last numbers. The way I have my method right now I am getting ERROR: Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type int[]

WHEN I USE
public static int[] lastStep(int[] numbers1) {

```
    //to get first
    int [] firstElement= numbers1.array[0];

    //last number
    int [] lastElement= numbers1.array[numbers1.size()-1];

}
return lastStep;
```

I get that array cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: To your last edit: You don't use `numbers1.array[0]`, it's just `numbers1[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using an `Array` not an `ArrayList`. Try using `numbers1[0]` and `numbers1[numbers.length - 1]`

You should consider changing your lastStep function. From what I can see, it does nothing, because the return statement is outside the function braces. There is also no variable `lastStep` inside the function that can be returned. Try the following:

```
public static string firstAndLast(int[] numberArray)
{
    return numberArray[0] + ", " + numberArray[numberArray.length - 1];
}
```

Then just call it like:

```
System.out.println(firstAndLast(numbers1));
```

Comment: I tryed that but I still have a error. Look at my code update up

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.get(0)` on an array, you have to use `array[0]`.

In your case it would be: `numbers1[0]`

Comment: public static int[] lastStep(int[] numbers1) {
  
  //to get first
  int [] firstElement= numbers1.array[0];
  
  //last number
  int [] lastElement= numbers1.array[numbers1.size()-1];
  
 }
 return lastStep;
 I am getting ERROR: array cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: You don't use `numbers1.array[0]`, it's just `numbers1[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use Array List for to add random numbers , then print the last and first one.